# How can I dynamically create a form WITHOUT jquery from a json field array?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'd like to create a form from a json array of fields, and have it call a callback on submit.

For example, I'd like something like the following, that would create a form with 3 fields, and call the onSubmitCallback when submit was clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var fc = new FormCreator({
    owner: document.body,
    fields: [
      {'name':'name', 'title':'name', 'value':'test'},
      {'name':'last_day', 'title':'last day', 'value':'test asdfas fdj'},
      {'name':'ez', 'title':'how', 'value':'test asdf'}
    ],
    config: {
      firstColWidth:'200px'
    },
    onSubmitCallback: function(data, form){
      console.log(data);
      return false;
    }
  });

</script>
```

Are there any examples out there for doing this?

Comment: ... Did you just ask a question and then answer it yourself within literally 1 second of each other?

Comment: Yeah I did! It's supported by the site as a way of supplying an answer to a question you couldn't find the answer to yourself.

Comment: Oh so like if you run into a problem that you can't find the solution to, but then you figure it out, you can post the question here with your solution for others to reference? That's neat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what you want - whipped together in about 30 min, so your results may vary!

```js
function FormCreator(options){
  this.options = options;
  this.createForm();
}

FormCreator.prototype.getFormValues = function(form)
{
  var result = {};
  for ( var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
     var e = form.elements[i];
     if (e.type != "text") 
     {
       continue;
     }
     result[e.name] = e.value;
  }
  return result;
}

FormCreator.prototype.addFormField = function(form, type, key, value)
{
  var field = document.createElement("input");
  field.setAttribute("type", type);
  field.setAttribute("name", key);
  field.setAttribute("value", value);

  form.appendChild(field);
}

FormCreator.prototype.createForm = function()
{
  var form = document.createElement('form');

  this.form = form;

  for (var i=0; i < this.options.fields.length; i++)
  {
    var field = this.options.fields[i];

    var label = document.createElement('span');
    var width = this.options.config.firstColWidth || '100px';
    label.style.cssText = 'min-width:' + width + ' !important; display: inline-block';
    var t = document.createTextNode(field.title || field.name);
    label.appendChild(t);
    form.appendChild(label);
    this.addFormField(form, 'text', field.name, field.value);

    var br = document.createElement('br');
    form.appendChild(br);
  }

  var me = this;
  form.onsubmit = function( e ) {
     e = e || window.event;
     if (! me.options.onSubmitCallback)
     {
       return false;
     }

     var data = me.getFormValues(form);
     var result = me.options.onSubmitCallback(data, form);
     if (result === undefined)
     {
       result = false;
     }
     return result;
  };

  this.options.owner.appendChild(form);
  this.addFormField(form, 'submit', 'submit', 'Submit');
  this.addFormField(form, 'reset', 'reset', 'Reset');
}

function test(){
  var fh = new FormCreator({
    owner: document.body,
    fields: [
      {'name':'name', 'title':'name', 'value':'test'},
      {'name':'last_day', 'title':'last day', 'value':'test \'asdfas\' fdj'},
      {'name':'ez', 'title':'how', 'value':'test "asdf'}
    ],
    config: {
      firstColWidth:'200px'
    },
    onSubmitCallback: function(data, form){
      alert("Data received. Look in console for results!");
      
      console.log(data);
      
      return false;
    }
  });
}

test();
```